# Temp Tables in a Stored Procedure will it cause recompilation of execution plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have `Temp Tables` being created in a stored procedure's definition and then `dropping them when I am done` with them will it result in recompilation of execution plan?

For stored procedures every time its called? Any personal Experience? 
Any explanation  please?

As when the temp tables are dropped at the end of every call, the execution plan becomes invalid. Does SQL Server still keep hold of the execution plan and reuse on next call or does it recompile it every time its called.

Comment: Often temporary tables in stored procedures are cached rather than created and dropped. See [Temporary Table Caching Explained](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx) for more about this.

Comment: Thank you for the link it is a very good read. Cheers @MartinSmith

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dropping of a temporary table doesn't matter. 
If a table is created (either permanent or temporary), all statement after that statement are recompiled (even if they don’t refer to the table). Calls to executable objects using EXEC aren’t recompiled. That's because SQL Server can create the plan after the objects are created. (In this case, the temp. table.)

You can monitor recompilation using Extended Events and its sql_statement_recompile or SQL Trace / SQL Server Profiler SQL:StmtRecompile.

1. A statement starts to execute. SP:StmtStarting or SQL:StmtStarting is raised
2. The statement is recompiled. SQL:StmtRecompile is raised. SP:StmtStarting or SQL:StmtStarting is raised again
3. The statement is finished. SP:StmtCompleted or SQL:StmtCompleted is raised

Not the whole procedure is recompiled but only individual statements.

Answer (score -2):

Generally speaking, any DDL in your store procedure will result in recompilation, then if you use create and drop table instructions you are going to get recompilations.
It can be mitigated by including the DDL as the first statement in the store procedure but you should test before and see it with your own eyes in your server.

If the dataset you have to put in the temporal table is small and you don't need non-unique indexes, you should try to use table variables instead.
It's not a good idea to put too many rows in a table variable because they dont have statistics, Sql Server allways "thinks" they have only one record and the query plan could be a little bit far than optimal one(but it is going to avoid the recompilations due to temporal table creation).

Comment: Not true for temp tables; sorry but I have to -1 this for that reason because it misleads based on the actual question (will create/drop temp tables cause recompilation)

See e.g. here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx, http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/17/temporary-object-caching-explained.aspx

Answer (score -3):

The temp tables can cause recompilation. It happens just because they are treated like the regular tables by the SQL Server Engine. When the tables (in which underlying queries rely on)
change significantly, SQL Server detects this change(using auto update statistics) and marks the dependent queries to be recompiled so that the next execution can create an optimal execution plan.

Once the temp table or the queries relying on the temp table changes the Query engine will not be able to execute the same cached plan as it would not accommodate the query.

It should be noted that table variables inherently do not cause recompilation. In some situations these may be a better choice.

See `http://sqlserverplanet.com/optimization/temp-table-recompiles` for further information on temp table recompilation.

Comment: Most of this answer is inaccurate: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx.  1) temp tables that are `CREATE`d and `DROP`ped can still be reused, and 2) unfortunately despite changes to data and statistics unless you explicitly recompile they will use the same plan